# How to print file from batch?

Tags: printing

If I use `NOTEPAD /P c:\myfile.txt`, it can't print the file because the batch file starts with `@echo off`.

Does someone know how to print the file?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I just tried printing from a batch file with `@echo off` and `@echo on` and it worked both ways - so I am not sure that is the issue.  Just FYI.

Comment: I am sure that the `@echo off` is NOT the issue.  Some more information about how the command fails would be helpful.

Comment: Do you have a printer setup as default? Is it a USB or network printer?

Comment: Is a network printer and the printer is default. If i run NOTEPAD /P c:\myfile.txt from clear batch file the file is printed.

Comment: Post the entire code.